# Разрешения Facebook Graph Api

Tags: facebook, facebook-api

Моя цель, получить информацию о пользователях facebook. В частности, пол, дата рождения, фио, места учебы.
Я получил так называемый "Маркер доступа пользователя", теперь по идее мне можно делать запросы и получать инфу, но нет, данные почему-то пустые.. кроме фио, id.

Вижу "Проверка входа", но никак не могу понять как она соотносится с моим задачами.  Я не хочу создавать публичное приложение, у которого будет аудитория или что-то вроде этого..

Вопрос, мне нужно в это вникать, и если да, то что вообще нужно им предоставлять... ?

Comment: А вы какие разрешения запрашивали когда получали маркер доступа?

Comment: Никаких дополнительных разрешений не запрашивал, вы хотите сказать, что при получении токена нужно запрашивать разрешения в самом запросе ? Насколько я понял, разрешения нужны для приложения..

Comment: Да, я добавил ответ, возможно вы просто не указали интересующие вас поля при получении токена

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, мне нужен токен пользователя или же приложения. Вы можете это пояснить ?

Comment: Вам нужен токен пользователя, я обновил ответ!

Answer (score 1):

В **Manifest.xml** должны быть прописаны следущие строки

```
<activity
    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    android:value="@string/fb_app_id" />
```

Если вы получаете токен подобным образом то вам нужно указать поля самостоятельно типа как `public_profile` список этих разрешений можете найти в документации.
Получая токен пользователя, вы вместе с запросом указываете поля:
`public_profile` , `user_friends` и т.д

```
 public void callLoginActivity() {
     LoginManager loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
     loginManager.setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.NATIVE_WITH_FALLBACK);
     loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(
         activity,
         Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", "read_custom_friendlists"));
 }
```

после того как вы залогинились и получили токен, вы можете делать запросы на получение, например списка друзей, для того что бы получить этих самых друзей, у вас должно быть разрешения на их получение, вот пример такого запроса:

```
public void getFriendsList() {
    AccessToken token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    String userId = token.getUserId();
    String path = "/friends";

    new GraphRequest(token, userId + path, null, HttpMethod.GET,
        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                /* handle the result */
                JSONArray data;
                ArrayList <FacebookUser> resultList = new ArrayList <FacebookUser> ();

                if (response.getError() == null) {
                    try {
                        //get data json object from response
                        data = response.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("data");

                        //loop data for get list of friends
                        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {

                            //get friend from array
                            JSONObject object = (JSONObject) data.get(i);
                            String name = object.getString("name");
                            long id = object.optLong("id", -1);

                            //put user data to model and save to result list
                            FacebookUser user = new FacebookUser();
                            user.setName(name);
                            user.setId(id);
                            resultList.add(user);
                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                Log.wtf(TAG, "Response error: " + response.getError());
                Log.wtf(TAG, "Raw: " + response.getRawResponse());
            }
        }
    ).executeAsync();
```

Для конкретного запроса вам нужны разрешения: "user_friends", "read_custom_friendlists". Т.е. если вам нужна еще какая то инфа о пользователе, вам нужно ее запрашивать при получении токена.